# Weird center formatting on a div around several floating divs

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to have a div of three divs, in which there is a left floating column, right floating column, and main content in the middle. I've tried what I could to do this, and I came up with this:

[image: An Error!]

For some reason, the middle div is centering between the end of the first column, and the end of the right column, not the beginning of the right.

```
<div id="main">
            <div id="left">
                <img src="/pic1.jpg" alt="Example work" height="250px" width="250px" />
                <br />
                <img src="/pic2.jpg" alt="Example work" height="250px" width="250px" />
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                words
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <img src="/pic3.jpg" alt="Example work" height="250px" width="250px" />
                <br />
                <img src="/pic4.jpg" alt="Example work" height="250px" width="250px" />
            </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#main {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
}

#left {
        float: left;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 2px ridge;
}

#right {
        float: right;
        padding: 5px;       
        border: 2px ridge;
}

#content {
        text-align: center;
}
```

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Float everything to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A right-floated element needs to come first in the markup.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vv4yA/

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <br />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
        <br />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" />
    </div>
    <div id="content">words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your content is pushed up against the left element, because the left element is floated. Your right element is floated right, IE against the parent. It doesn't interact with the content element, they essentially overlap. What you really want is three elements floated left, so each one starts where the other stops.

I would put a width of 10% on the left and right elements so they all add up to 100%, using box-sizing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Develop quicker by using scaffolding. Try [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)

You can customize it by using just the scaffolding, if you'd like.